# Сравнение значения в нескольких столбцах, создание отдельного файла с содержимым строк, подходящим по результату

Tags: vba, макросы

Задача макроса следующая, сравнить цифры в трёх столбцах
если в первом столбце 0, во втором 200, а в третьем 30 то создать файл, в котором будет строка с со значением 30) Или если 1-20 2-1000 3-25 то значение будет 5.

Суть в том чтобы сформировался список строк, в котором значение в столбце 3 меньше чем в 1, с учетом 2, если 1 и 3 столбец равны, то строку пропускаем, если 1<3 на "а" и "a" < 2 столбца, то создаем в новом файле строку в которой будет значение из 4 столбца + результат разницы 1 и 3 столбца. Например
Дано

```
1    2    3    4
10   20   15   Q
2    20   15   D
3    20   3    P
```

Результат

```
1    2
Q    5
D    13
```

---

Есть файл exсel в котором используется 4 столбца, три из них это просто цифры, а один описание. Так вот задача в том, чтобы сравнить цифры из первого столбца с третьим, с учетом второго. Получается надо взять посмотреть сколько в третьем столбе (к примеру там цифра 50), и вычесть из него цифру которая указана в первом столбце (например 10), и наш результат (в данном случае получится 40) перенести в новый файл excel, но если во втором столбце цифра 0 или меньше 40(исходя из примера) , то результат будет цифра из столбца два(если во втором столбце 30, а это меньше 40)) то и результат будет 30. В итоге полученную цифру + описание из четвертого столбца, нужно перенести в новый файл excel. И так сделать для всех имеющихся строк(порядка 2000)

---

Я конечно не программист, но думаю, сам макрос должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
#Переменные
    var a (первый столбец с описанием)
    var b (второй столбец)
    var c (третий столбец)
    var d (четвертый столбец)
    var T (результат)
    
    if b<c
       T = b-c
    If t<=d
       t=d
    
    promt a + T # результат записываем в новый файл эксель в первую строку
```

Comment: После прочтения мозги набекрень... То ли Вы ресурс перепутали и прямой путь на форум головоломок, то ли стоит задуматься о донесении своих мыслей до других. Первый абзац, как я понял, пример решения. В таком случае он должен быть в конце текста, иначе сразу мозги в узел заворачиваются.   `===с учетом 2, если 1 и 3 столбец равны` - учитывать какую-то двойку, второе условие или второй столбец? ===*значение из 4 столбца + результат разницы 1 и 3 столбца* - очередной нокаут извилинам. В конце вопроса в первой строке примера слева единица, но в исходных она в первом столбце, а не в четвертом...

Comment: Учитывает значение из столбца два.

Comment: Перенесите в комментарии все то, что вы написали в ответах. Согласно правил сообщества, вы должны указать, что именно сделали самостоятельно и что у вас не получилось. На данный момент вопрос похож на запрос решения домашнего задания (лабораторной работы). Данный ресурс не для подобных вопросов.